# DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: expirationDate, at position 10

Tags: datetime, parsing, plotly-python, scatter-matrix

[Parse Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEXNU.png)

Expiration Date is already in datetime format, yet it is complaining. For some reason dateitme column appears as object as opposed to datetime when df.info() is used which is very puzzling to say the least.

[result of df.info()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhA8O.png)

Any guidance will be very much appreciated. This has been a real pain to get around it.